Error con al intentar usar extensión de lib gdx 'gdx-video'
Es para un proyecto en lib gdx en pc en donde quiero reproducir una cinemática.
He intentado con gemini, claude y chat gpt y ninguno me ayudó... todo loo que me dijieron lo hice paso a paso y me tira error. Inclso mire en google, youtube y nada.
Puse dependencias en el build:gradle y no las encontraba
Puse repositorios y probe con otras versiones de lib gdx y tampoco.
Ya no sé que hacerr :/
Lo que yo quiero es traerme con una dependencia la clase VideoPlayer para poder reproducir un video al comienzo de mi juego.
1- Puse esto en el archivo gradle:build(core):
implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-video:$gdxVersion"
implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-video-desktop:$gdxVersion"

2- Agrege el repositorio en el gradle:build principal (el primero que aparece en la carpeta de un proyecto de lib gdx). Probe sacandola y tampoco
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

// también probe cambiando eso por 1.12.1 que es mi gdxversion.

me tira error:


What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating project ':lwjgl3'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':lwjgl3:runtimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-video:1.12.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/badlogicgames/gdx/gdx-video/1.12.1/gdx-video-1.12.1.pom
       - https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/com/badlogicgames/gdx/gdx-video/1.12.1/gdx-video-1.12.1.pom
       - file:/C:/Users/iansa/.m2/repository/com/badlogicgames/gdx/gdx-video/1.12.1/gdx-video-1.12.1.pom
       - https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/badlogicgames/gdx/gdx-video/1.12.1/gdx-video-1.12.1.pom
       - https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/badlogicgames/gdx/gdx-video/1.12.1/gdx-video-1.12.1.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/com/badlogicgames/gdx/gdx-video/1.12.1/gdx-video-1.12.1.pom
     Required by:
         project :lwjgl3 > project :core
   > Could not find com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-video-desktop:1.12.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
 //links

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org. Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not

find com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-video:1.12.1.


Acá busqué en el github de la extensión de lib gdx pero también me tira el mismo error
Paso repositrio de github para que vean la estructura del proyecto: https://github.com/ian-svn/Rise-Of-The-Fallen/tree/master

Hola Ian, bienvenido, te sugiero editar tu pregunta y agregar el código y los mensajes de error (todo como texto), sino tu pregunta será cerrada.

Muestra el error, como agregaste la lib, y que esperas hacer.

Ahí la edité, gracias.

El error indica que no puede encontrar la versión del módulo que definiste:

Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException:
Could not find com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-video:1.12.1.

Pero el problema específicamente es que la dependencia que definiste es incorrecta.
Revisando la documentación de GDX-Video, estas serían las dependencias a definir en tu archivo build.gradle:
Core:
implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx-video:gdx-video:$gdxVideoVersion"

Desktop:
implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx-video:gdx-video-lwjgl3:$gdxVideoVersion"
// or (when using legacy LWJGL2):
implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx-video:gdx-video-lwjgl:$gdxVideoVersion"


Gracias pero es exacto lo que mande en la foto, o sea que ya lo intenté y me tira lo mimso

en todo cado si pudiese explicar en donde exactamente se ponen esas lineas de código por ahí me ayudarías. porque hay 3 build:gradle y no se en que parte del codigo ponerlas.

Debes tenerlas en el archivo app/build.gradle , es donde se definen las dependencias, targetSdkVersion, compileSdk, applicationId etc!

tengo 3 build:gradle, podes fijarte en el github que mande sino, uno en Peleita/build.gradle, otro en lwjgl3/build.gradle y otro en core/build.gradle.
No se en cual ni en donde poner esas lineas.
